# cakephp: login form not redirecting

Tags: cakephp, redirect, authentication

When I click the login button on the login form, nothing happens. It is not redirecting to /merry_parents/report_card. I have specified $this->Auth->loginRedirect in beforeFilter. Does anyone know on what i'm doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Following is my merry_parents controller, login view and report_card view

app_controller.php

```
   class AppController extends Controller {


var $components=array('Auth','Session');

function beforeFilter(){
  if (isset($this->Auth)){
        $this->Auth->userModel='MerryParent';
        $this->Auth->loginAction=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'report_card');
        $this->Auth->allow('signup','login','logout');
        $this->Auth->authorize='controller';
        //$this->Auth->actionPath='controllers/';
      }
   else
        $this->Session->setFlash('Auth has not been set');  

}

function isAuthorized(){
    return true;
}
   }
```

merry_parents_controller.php

```
    class MerryParentsController extends AppController{

var $name='MerryParents';
var $components=array('Acl','Auth','Session');


function report_card(){
}

function register(){

}

function login(){

}

function logout(){
$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

function signup(){
        print_r($this->data);

    if (!empty($this->data)){
        //$this->Auth->password($this->data['MerryParent']['password2'] used to get what the hashed password2 would look like.        
        $this->MerryParent->set($this->data);
         //validates calls invalidFields methods which in turn populates validationErrors arrays. Validates is used to validate a record prior to updating. Needed only when you want to update certain fields in an existing record.
         if ($this->MerryParent->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('username','email','password','password2')))){

             if ($this->data['MerryParent']['password']==$this->Auth->password($this->data['MerryParent']['password2'])){

                     $this->MerryParent->id=$this->MerryParent->field('id',
                                                    array('MerryParent.username'=>$this->data['MerryParent']['username'],
                                                    'MerryParent.email'=>$this->data['MerryParent']['email'])
                                                    );
                    echo $this->MerryParent->id;

                    //die(debug($this->MerryParent->validationErrors));
                    if ($this->MerryParent->save($this->data,false))//record with $this->MerryParent->id is updated
                        {
                                                    $this->Auth->login($this->data); //automatically logs a user in after registration

                        $this->redirect('/merry_parents/report_card');
                        }
                    else
                        echo $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your admission could not be saved, please try again!',true));


                }//end if ($this->data['MerryParent']['password']....
                else
                    echo $this->Session->setFlash('Typed passwords did not match');
            }//if ($this->MerryParent->validates
    }//end if (!empty($this->data))
}
 }
 ?>
```

login.ctp

```
  <?php
       echo $this->Form->create('MerryParent',array('action'=>'login'));
      echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>'Name'));
      echo $this->Form->input('password', array('value'=>''));
      echo $this->Form->end('Login');
   ?>
```

report_card.ctp

```
 <?php
 echo 'HALLO';

 ?>
```

Comment: "nothing happens"? the form is not submitted? Then it's browser's problem. And I think you have the wrong idea about what loginAction is...

Comment: from my reading from cakephp cookbook, loginAction is used to change the default login from/users/login to any other action action of your choice. So, thats what i've done here, i have changed the default /users/login to /merry_parents/register which displays the signup link and login link.

Comment: that's not good way to do it (the reason is a little long and off-topic right now, but you'll see). You haven't answer about "nothing happends"?

Comment: yes, nothing happens, the form is NOT submitted. When i click submit, it stays on the same page.

Comment: after modifying beforeFilter, it is redirecting to /merry_parents/report_card for signup. But it still doesn't work for login. When i click the login button, it stays on the same page. it is not getting redirected to /merry_parents/report_card as specified in $this->Auth->loginRedirect. I also observed that loginRedirect doesn't work for signup. For that, it makes use of $this->redirect as specified in signup function.

Comment: have you tried putting the loginAction to go to login to see if it works? how is register.ctp doing the login part? does it try to load something on submit? try var_dump($this->data) at the beginning of the view. I always use login as loginAction, change it and you have to use al login related with that action, like the url of the form, etc...

Comment: Ok, i've changed loginAction to login. It doesn't load report_card on submit. When I try var_dump($this->data), i'm getting array(1) { ["MerryParent"]=> array(2) { ["username"]=> string(4) "hong" ["password"]=> NULL } } . I guess password NULL is causing the problem. I don't understand ur last sentence: "I always use login as loginAction, change it and you have to use al login related with that action, like the url of the form, etc..."

Comment: Ok, both signup and login are working fine when I put the beforeFilter in app_controller.php. I also changed loginAction to login as suggested by api55. Thanks a lot for all the help.